# UIScrollView does not scroll in customView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm making a custom view and it contains a `UIScrollView`. But this scroll view does not scroll.

The view hierarchy is as follows:

```
- mainView
    - UIScrollView
        - contentView
```

[A picture for illustration purposes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enPPq.png)

Here is my custom view code:

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollViewContetnView: UIView!

    // MARK: - Methods

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.customInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.customInit()
    }

    // MARK: Custom

    func customInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("EmoKeyboard", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(mainView)
        self.mainView.frame = self.bounds
        self.mainView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }

    func makeTabItem(count: Int) {
        for i in 0...count {
            let icon = UIButton()
            icon.frame.size = CGSize(width: 28, height: 28)
            icon.center.y = self.scrollViewContentView.center.y
            icon.frame.origin.x = 10 + (CGFloat(i) * 28) + (CGFloat(i) * 10)
            icon.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

            self.scrollViewContentView.addSubview(icon)
        }
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell and I've only looked at doing this kind of thing through the storyboard, which requires the content view to be constrained to all edges of the scrollview, with edge you want to grow having a lower priority.

Comment: You need update frame for scrollViewContentView, and contentsize for scrollView.

Comment: Have you checked the isUserInteractionEnabled property on your mainView and your scrollView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually set `contentSize` of your `scrollView` based on buttons count or for every button add constraints.
Another possible(!) easier way is adding `UIStackView` as subview of your `scrollView` and add each button with height/width constraints to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `contentSize`:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 900) //You can use self view size height to set height means replace 900 according to your requirment
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you add a `UIButton` to your `scrollViewContentView`, you should update the width of the `scrollViewContentView`, because its width should be equal to the width of all the `UIButton items` that you are adding to it plus the sum of spacing between the items.

Answer (score 0):

1. calculate the content rect in 
   ViewController ~> viewDidLayoutSubviews

   var contentRect = CGRect.zero

   for view in contentView.subviews {
        contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
    }

   contentRect = contentRect.union(padding)
2. apply the rect

   scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size